# how can i split the string with the cammas that are not embeded in braces , brackets and qutations from a string with php

Tags: php, regex, extract

--eddited--

how can i split the string with the cammas that are not embeded in braces , brackets and qutations from a string with php

Comment: no only that , the string may be anything -- imagine that strings parts are the arguments of a php function and may be diffrent

Comment: Can you not just use another separator instead of comma. you can user your own separator and just use explode function. eg explode("custom_separator ",$str)

Comment: @SJB this way is just Bypass problem || i cant use another separator

Comment: Yes. if there there is better way to do it..shouldnt we use that..

Comment: @SJB `@include('app',['username'=>'john','title'=>'the title'])` this code is for laravel Do you really think the laravel development use `explode funnction` for extract the include function Argument  in blade? (This is just a sample that you get noticed )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use **lookarounds**:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
func('name','family,address') , "lorem ipsom, is a..." , ['name','part']
DATA;

$regex = '~(?<=\ ),(?=\h)~';

$parts = preg_split($regex, $data);
print_r($parts);
?>
```

---

See [**a working demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/hImM9Y).

---

Even better yet would be a `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
func('name','family,address') , "lorem ipsom, is a..." , ['name','part']
DATA;

$regex = '~
            (\w+\([^)]+\)
            |
            "[^"]+"
            |
            \[[^]]+\]
            (*SKIP)(*FAIL))
            |
            \h*,\h*
        ~x';

$parts = preg_split($regex, $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($parts);
?>
```

See [**a demo for this one on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/PxVd8x) as well.

Comment: thank you but maybe does not space around camma

Comment: @MortazaFaryabi: I guessed so - please provide more realistic input strings then, maybe we can help with the abovementioned `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.

Comment: so, how php split the arguments in  `func('name','family,address') , "lorem ipsom, is a..." , ['name','part']`

Comment: My question is it ,  in fact,    `how can i split the string with the cammas that are not embeded in braces , brackets and qutations from a string with php`,

Comment: @MortazaFaryabi: See the updated answer at the bottom (`*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.

Comment: thank you, but `[^"]` used in your sulation and in [] maybe double qutation ,so your soulation does not work at all times ,for this reasons I try and try and try! to write a regex for extract arguments or separation cammas and i write a [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gM0xC9/2) see that do you see a problem in that or when not working?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$elements = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: there are some cammas in the each parts for this reasons explode does not help me

Comment: Ok can u send or share here string ? Then i can update u